# Find input field inside a div Tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jQuery function I read the div tag into variable. There are many text fields inside that div tag. I want to get specific field by its name.

Tag:

```
  var guest_html=$('#guests_feilds1').html();
```

Get field:

```
  guest_html.getElementById('fname');
```

But this will return error "has no method 'getElementById' ".

I just want to get the "fname" field and change its name dynamically.How can i do that?

Comment: what is fname? id or name of input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`guest_html` is a string so doesn't have method `getElementById`.

What you need is:

```
// since you use getElementById('fname'), I assume fname is an id
$('#fname').attr('name', 'foo'); // change the name of the element with id fname
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parentHtmlTag = $('#guests_feilds1');

    // Getting fname value
    var fname = parentHtmlTag.find('#fname').val();
    alert('First Name : '+fname);

    // Setting value of fname dynamically
    var newFname = parentHtmlTag.find('#fname').val('Test');
    alert('New First Name : '+newFname);          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

`var guest_html=$('#guests_feilds1').html();`

To

`var guest_html=$('#guests_feilds1');`

You need to get the object reference, not the inner content.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as:

```
var div = $('#guests_feilds1');

# finding using ID:
div.find('#input1').val()

# finding using name:
div.find("input[name='your_input_name']").val()
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/budhram/T4Mr4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

var guest_html= $('#guests_feilds1');

var inputT = $(this).find('input[name="name"]');

console.log(inputT)

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one element with id 'fname',  then you can directly use 
document.getElementById('fname'), rather calling it on an object

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('frame').value; will give you the value. 
Now you can change dynamically...